# sass intellisense visual studio 2015 @extend

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, sass

I am attempting to use the @extend to get bootstrap css intellisense in a scss stylesheet. It works and compiles the right code to a css stylesheet but i get no intellisense. I am using VS 2015 with web compiler and web essentials 2015.2. I am assuming it is the compiler itself(web compiler) or something i don't have set up right. It is kind of useless without intellisense as i am new to bootstrap. I get other @extend intellisense options for regular css but not from an imported scss file. Some additional info is that it is a asp.net core 1.0 web project with an empty template as a start and i imported bootstrap thru bower. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add reference comments to the top of your `scss` file for each imported file. This is the same as we would do for JavaScript.

**Example**

```
/// <reference path="_your-scss-file.scss" />
```

This will give you intellisense for the referenced file.

For more info, I have written an [article](https://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/get-intellisense-in-sass-less-files-in-visual-studio)

Comment: whhen i use your above reference path It expects a : character instead of = but still produces error and gives me css psuedo selectors so it seems to not lead down a path of bringing in intellisense into my scss file. Maybe i am missing something. I think the answer is in some sort of gulp function. But not sure. If anyone knows please help. Thanks

Comment: I had been using this method for a long time, but now my projects are being structured in a way where I have multiple folders each containing several scss files and an "all" scss file that simply imports everything in the folder. My main.scss would then just import those "all" files. However, the reference tag only works when the referenced file contains the mixins, they cannot be transitively included via @import. Is there any way around this (using VS2017)?